# tfjs-node tf.constant not a function error

Tags: tfjs-node

Simple code that works fine in python environment was rewritten to run in node js but I can't seem to get it to work.

The node js code looks like:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

var x= tf.constant([10, 20, 30])
var y= tf.constant([ 2, 3, 5])  
var z= tf.divide(x, y)
```

I get the following errors when I run this code:

```
Overriding the gradient for 'Max'
Overriding the gradient for 'OneHot'
Overriding the gradient for 'PadV2'
Overriding the gradient for 'SpaceToBatchND'
Overriding the gradient for 'SplitV'
2020-07-01 13:31:52.548282: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-07-01 13:31:52.573722: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x104718410 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-07-01 13:31:52.573765: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
/Users/rodney/Desktop/node_code/ccx_MultiTool/playground/test18.js:3
var x= tf.constant([10, 20, 30])
          ^
TypeError: tf.constant is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rodney/Desktop/node_code/ccx_MultiTool/playground/test18.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(base)
```

I'd like to know two things:

1. how to get rid of the overriding errors
2. why I'm getting the TypeError: tf.constant is not a func

I'm running the code on a Macintosh 10.15.5 Catalina

and tf.version returns the following:

```
{
 'tfjs-core': '2.0.1',
  'tfjs-backend-cpu': '2.0.1',
  'tfjs-backend-webgl': '2.0.1',
  'tfjs-data': '2.0.1',
  'tfjs-layers': '2.0.1',
  'tfjs-converter': '2.0.1',
  tfjs: '2.0.1',
  'tfjs-node': '2.0.1'
}
```

Because this returns data I know that some things are working.

Comment: I have fixed the divide error and most of the warnings by modifying the code. Apparently tf.divide does not exist and you must use tf.div

I only found this error by printing out all the functions supported using:

console.dir(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(tf), null, 4))

And I noticed tf.div not tf.divide as the documentation specifies

I also set the Environment variable  named TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL using:

export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3

Comment: Code now looks like:
`// to get rid of most of the warning measages,set the TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL environment level using
// export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3

const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

// console.dir(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(tf), null, 4))


var x= [10, 20, 30]
var y= [ 2, 3, 5]  
var z= tf.div(x,y)


// console.log('z:',z)
tf.print(z)`

and the errors look like:

Overriding the gradient for 'Max'
Overriding the gradient for 'OneHot'
Overriding the gradient for 'PadV2'
Overriding the gradient for 'SpaceToBatchND'
Overriding the gradient for 'SplitV'